# implicit Objective-C entrypoint -[setPeriod_end_date:] is deprecated

Tags: swift

I have a data type called 'Subscription' with this data

```
var id: String = ""
var card: SCard?
var plan_id: String = ""
var status: String = ""    
var cancel_at_period_end: Int = 0 // 1 canceled, 0 active
var period_end_date: String = ""
var trial_end_date: String = ""
var benefits: Benefits?
```

And an init method that helps me fill the values

```
init (dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        super.init ()
        setValuesForKeys (dictionary)
}
```

In the method 'setValuesForKeys' I use the super.setValue method

```
let uppercasedFirstCharacter = String (key.first!). uppercased ()
let range = NSMakeRange (0, 1)
let selectorString = NSString (string: key) .replacingCharacters (in: range, with: uppercasedFirstCharacter)
let selector = NSSelectorFromString ("set \ (selectorString):")
let responds = self.responds (to: selector)
if! responds {
    return
}
super.setValue (value, forKey: key)
```

but this 'Warning' marks me

```
implicit Objective-C entrypoint - [Suscription setPeriod_end_date:] is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 4
implicit Objective-C entrypoint - [Suscription setPlan_id:] is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 4
implicit Objective-C entrypoint - [Suscription setStatus:] is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 4
implicit Objective-C entrypoint - [Suscription setTrial_end_date:] is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 4
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this setting:

Targets -> Build Settings -> search "Inference" -> change the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" to "Default".